# Logical OR constraint in PulP

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pulp

I am new to PulP. Below is the optimization problem.

Consider x11, x12, x13 be units of FG1 to be loaded on Medium Truck 1, Small Truck and Medium Truck 2 respectively. Similarly, consider x21,x22,x23 be variables to denote units of FG2 to be loaded on Medium Truck 1, Small Truck and Medium Truck 2 respectively.

The objective here is to distribute both products total qty = 2011 (FG1 = 900, FG2 = 1111) in 2 Medium Trucks and 1 Small Truck. There are some constraints wrt to area, volume and weights which are mentioned.

There is an additional constraint that if FG1 has to be loaded in any of the trucks, minimum qty should be 60 if not 0. Means either load more than or equal to 60 or 0. I am not able to figure out how to model such constraint. Please suggest.

##### Current code:

```
from pulp import LpMinimize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable

solver = pl.GLPK_CMD()

model = LpProblem(name="load_receipts", sense=LpMinimize)

x11 = LpVariable(name="x11", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x12 = LpVariable(name="x12", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x13 = LpVariable(name="x13", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x21 = LpVariable(name="x21", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x22 = LpVariable(name="x22", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x23 = LpVariable(name="x23", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

model += (0.5*x11 + 0.333333*x21 <=  400)
model += (0.5*x12 + 0.333333*x22 <=  200)
model += (0.5*x13 + 0.333333*x23 <=  400)
model += (0.25*x11 + 0.142857*x21 <=  200)
model += (0.25*x12 + 0.142857*x22 <=  100)
model += (0.25*x13 + 0.142857*x23 <=  200)
model += (0.001*x11 + 0.000125*x21 <=  50)
model += (0.001*x12 + 0.000125*x22 <=  25)
model += (0.001*x13 + 0.000125*x23 <=  50)
model += (x11 + x12 + x13 + x21 + x22 + x23 - 2011 == 0)
model += (x11 + x12 + x13 == 900)
model += (x21 + x22 + x23 == 1111)

model += x11 + x12 + x13 + x21 + x22 + x23-2011

status = model.solve(solver)

print(f"status: {model.status}, {LpStatus[model.status]}")
for var in model.variables():
    print(f"{var.name}: {var.value()}")
```

Comment: You should post the code into the main body of the question...  I moved it up for you.  Next time, all you have to do is select the code from wherever, paste it in to the question, then re-select all the code (only) and hit ctrl-k (or cmd-k on Mac).  Also, you probably should exclude the install commands from your code.  You can delete the "placeholder" answer below to clean up the question...

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install PulP
from pulp import LpMinimize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable

!apt-get install -y -qq glpk-utils
import pulp as pl
solver = pl.GLPK_CMD()

model = LpProblem(name="load_receipts", sense=LpMinimize)

x11 = LpVariable(name="x11", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x12 = LpVariable(name="x12", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x13 = LpVariable(name="x13", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x21 = LpVariable(name="x21", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x22 = LpVariable(name="x22", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
x23 = LpVariable(name="x23", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

model += (0.5*x11 + 0.333333*x21 <=  400)
model += (0.5*x12 + 0.333333*x22 <=  200)
model += (0.5*x13 + 0.333333*x23 <=  400)
model += (0.25*x11 + 0.142857*x21 <=  200)
model += (0.25*x12 + 0.142857*x22 <=  100)
model += (0.25*x13 + 0.142857*x23 <=  200)
model += (0.001*x11 + 0.000125*x21 <=  50)
model += (0.001*x12 + 0.000125*x22 <=  25)
model += (0.001*x13 + 0.000125*x23 <=  50)
model += (x11 + x12 + x13 + x21 + x22 + x23 - 2011 == 0)
model += (x11 + x12 + x13 == 900)
model += (x21 + x22 + x23 == 1111)

model += x11 + x12 + x13 + x21 + x22 + x23-2011

status = model.solve(solver)

print(f"status: {model.status}, {LpStatus[model.status]}")
for var in model.variables():
    print(f"{var.name}: {var.value()}")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The general concept you are looking for here is the use of a binary "indicator" variable and a big-M constraint needed to connect that binary variable back to the quantity variable.

In pseudocode, let's let:

```
X = amount of commodity to load
Y = binary variable indicating if more than min load is loaded
min_load = the minimal amount to load (or nothing) in your example, 60
M = some large value (constant) that is larger than the max value that could be loaded
```

Then you need two constraints each time you want to implement this restriction:

```
Y * min_load <= X        # clamp Y to zero unless the minimum is loaded
X <= Y * M               # clamp X to zero unless Y is 1, then enable up to M
```

Answer (score 0):

*Means either load more than or equal to 60 or 0.*

This is called a semi-continuous variable. Many systems have special facilities for this allowing you to declare a variable as being semi-continuous. PuLP does not have this, so you can simulate this with a binary variable δ:

```
δ⋅L ≤ x ≤ δ⋅U
δ ∈ {0,1}
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample for this?

Comment: @MatheusTorquato What have you tried and what is the stumbling block? Should be trivial.