# How to make OR condition in pulp library variables?

Tags: python, variables, conditional-statements, linear-programming, pulp

for i in range(N):
n[i] = LpVariable('n'+str(i), lowBound = m[i], cat='Integer')

'This will create: infinity > n[i] >`= m[i]'

```
(N,A,C) = (3,10,12)
c = [2,3,5]
a = [1,2,3]
f = [3,4,8]
m = [2,2,1]
n = [0] * N
  
prob = LpProblem("Problem",LpMaximize)

for i in range(N):
    n[i] = LpVariable('n'+str(i), lowBound = m[i], cat = 'Integer')
    
prob += lpSum([f[i]*n[i] for i in range(N)]), "profit"

prob += lpSum([a[i]*n[i] for i in range(N)]) <= A, "Area"
prob += lpSum([c[i]*n[i] for i in range(N)]) <= C, "Cost"

prob.solve()
```

I want to write condition something like

for i in range(N):
prob += (n[i] >= m[i]) or (n[i] == 0)

'This mean: infinity > n[i] >= m[i] or n[i] == 0, it can be equaled to 0 or bigger than m[i]

Comment: could you format your code appropiately?

Comment: I just pose my code, is it help ? 
In my code, I only have n[i] >= m[i] but I want it to n[i] == 0 or n[i] >= m[i]
For example: x > 3 or x =0, That's what I want

Comment: This is covered in this answer and the other one in this post covering semi-continuous variables:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74319829/logical-or-constraint-in-pulp/74320239#74320239 .  Remove the lower bound, make another vector of binary variables as described in that answer.